# Using Linux live USB to bit copy a single directory from a corrupted hard disk

Tags: data-recovery

I'd like to recover the contents of a directory from a Windows 7 machine with a corrupted hard drive. So far I've been able to boot up the machine with an Ubuntu live USB, and the Windows 7 drive is mounted but I cannot list all the contents of the subdirectory that I'd like to recover. I've also tried copying the directory with `rsync --ignore-errors` but did not get great results. Now I'd like to try a bitcopy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While doing so would be cool and reduce stress on the already damaged drive, the tools freely available in Linux are not really good at handling damaged NTFS. The only practical thing you can do is copying the *entire* partition (or even the entire hard-drive) to a new one, then use Windows tools to examine it. I recommend [ddrescue](https://forensicswiki.xyz/wiki/index.php?title=Ddrescue#Kernel_2.6.3.2B_.26_ddrescue_1.4.2B):

```
ddrescue /dev/damaged /dev/new logfile
```

In case the file-system is damaged beyond any use, you can try to pull individual files from the drive using testdisk, photorec or other scraping tools. Be warned, though: Results are often disappointing.

Comment: the rescue succeeded and I can view the files but I cannot copy them as I keep getting "unable to read fragment cache entry" or "unable to read page" errors.

Comment: @Olumide Those errors are related to squashfs. How does it come into play? Windows is typically using NTFS.